# How to reflect the entire CARTESIAN co-ordinate system to a line.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to reflect every point possible in $R^2$ onto the line x+2y=0

Clearly we have a line equation with gradient :$ M= -1/2$

How do i find a suitable matrix to reflect all points to this line.
I'd appreciate any method, the more the better, thank you.

Comment: I've thought of maybe reflecting the line onto the x=axis and the reflecting all points onto the x-axis as well...Although I actually dont think that this makes sense

Comment: You'd probably be more successful rotating the line of reflection to coincide with one of the axes, performing the reflection, then rotating back.  This would result in the product of three matrices whose forms are relatively straightforward/well known.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** More or less by definition, the reflection matrix fixes vectors parallel to the line and maps vectors orthogonal to the line to their negatives. These facts together give you geometric description of the eigenspaces along with their corresponding eigenvalues, and one can immediately reconstruct the matrix from these.

Answer (score 1):

*If* a map is linear, a smart way to figure out its matrix is to figure out where the matrix takes the standard basis.  That is, with $v_1 = (1,0)^T, v_2 = (0,1)^T$ the standard basis and $M$ the matrix, we want to know, by whatever method, what are $Mv_1$ and $Mv_2$.  Since we don't know $M$ yet, we have to use other ways to find these two results.  Once we do, however, we can recover $M$ as $\left( Mv_1 ~ Mv_2 \right)$.  That is, the first column is $Mv_1$ and the second column is $Mv_2$.  A way to remind yourself that this works is to simulate (in your mind) what happens when we mutiply this matrix by $v_1$:  from the first row, it picks out the element in the first column.  From the second row, it picks out the element in the first column, et c...  It picks out the first element from each row and collects those into a vector.  Thus, we get the first column as output; we get $Mv_1$, as required.  Similarly, multiplication with $v_2$ picks out the second column and further, multiplication with $v_k$ picks out the $k^\text{th}$ column.

So, by any means we like we want to know where this reflection takes $v_1$ and $v_2$.  The line $x + 2y = 0$ can be written in slope-intercept form as $y = \frac{-1}{2}x + 0$.  When a point is reflected through a line, it starts and ends on a perpendicular to that line.  The slope of a line perpendicular to $y = \frac{-1}{2}x + 0$ has slope $\frac{-1}{-1/2} = 2$.  So the point at the end of $v_1$ is mapped somewhere on the line $y-0 = 2 (x-1) = 2x-2$.  The distance of the point from the line of reflection is the same before and after the reflection, so we should find this distance.  For this point, this is the distance between it and the point where the two lines intersect.  The line of reflection satisfies $x = -2y$, which we substitute to find $y-0 = 2(-2y)-2$, or $5y = -2$, which gives $y = -2/5$ and backsubstituting, $x=4/5$.  The distance is then $\sqrt{(1-4/5)^2 + (0--2/5)^2}$.  Finding the reflected point is then straightforward.  Repeat for the point at the end of $v_2$ and you have the two columns of your desired matrix.